# Does Datastax Enterprise 4.5 support spark streaming?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

Some of the marketing materials imply that it does but the documentation flatly states that it does not. So I am wondering is there a plan to support it soon if its truly not supported?

Comment: Check out this webinar on Cassandra & Spark- http://bit.ly/1FrP3Li

Answer (score 2):

While DataStax Enterprise 4.5 does use the DataStax Open Source Spark Connector which has streaming included, streaming was not officially supported by Datastax. You can still utilize it and write streaming applications.

The official tested release with streaming fully supported by Datastax is 4.6 which should be out very close to now. This version also includes more demos illustrating building streaming applications against DSE libraries and writing custom receivers.